# How to resolve Socket hang up issue in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to call rest API call from on EC2 server to other EC2 server,
getting the issue like Socket Hang up 404. Could you please suggest me how to
resolve that issue.
Both the servers are running fine and there is no cache connectivity between
the two servers also good.